# Angular2 Poller Reset ng-bootstrap accordin

Tags: angular, rxjs, ng-bootstrap

I have a multi dimensional array hooked up to a reactive poller that waits for a database state update. If i load the state 1x the ui works as expected.

Problem: When i turn on the poller, it causes the accordion state to close.

Code:

```
<ngb-accordion #acc="ngbAccordion" [closeOthers]="true">
    <ngb-panel *ngFor="let group of fishGroups | async" title="{{group[0].source.originalname}}">
        <template ngbPanelContent>
            ......
        </template>
    </ngb-panel>
</ngb-accordion>


ngOnInit() {
  console.log('ngOnInit');

  this.fishGroups = this.fisheService.elements
    //ensure not null
    .filter((arr: DTOfish[]) => (arr != null && arr.length > 0))
    // create milti dimensional array

    .map((fishes : DTOfish[]) => {
      let groups: DTOfish[][] = [];
      fishes.forEach((fish: DTOfish) => {
        //note double assignment : if null create
        let group: DTOfish[] = groups[fish.source.id] = groups[fish.source.id] ? groups[fish.source.id] : [];
        group.push(fish);
      });

      //make sparse array dense
      return groups.filter(value => !!value);
    });

  this.fishes = this.fisheService.elements.map((fishes: DTOfish[]) => {
    return fishes.filter((fish: DTOfish) => !fish.model.isFailed)
  });


  this.fisheService.loadAll();

  this._interval = global.setInterval( () => {
    console.log('fishComponent Poller');
    this.fisheService.loadAll();
  }, 2000);

}
```

**Question:** 
How do i keep the selected content panel open when the poller returns an update state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The component takes a value OR array of active element ids. All values in the variable will be left open when a change in your data occurs.

```
@Input() activeIds: string | string[] = [];
```

https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/accordion/accordion.ts#L131